How do I convert an id = ANY(ARRAY(select ...)) to sqlalchemy
I have the following simplified query
WITH users as (
   SELECT *
   FROM users
   WHERE created_at >= '2024-01-01'
)
SELECT *
FROM emails
WHERE user_id = ANY(ARRAY(SELECT id FROM users))

I need to use ANY(ARRAY()) over a simple IN since this forces the optimizer to take a better plan that makes a significant impact.
How do I convert this into SQLAlchemy?
I tried something like this but it keeps failing
users_cte = select(User.id, User.name).filter(User.created_at >= date(2024, 01, 01)).cte("user_cte")

select(
   emails.address
)
.filter(Email.user_id.any_(func.array(select(users.cte.id))))

This results in
TypeError: ColumnOperators.any_() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Is this possible to do in sqlalchemy?

I think you want to use any in an expression rather than calling a column's any method.
tbl.c.id == sa.any(sa.func.array(sa.select(other_tbl.c.id)))

This example code uses slightly different tables, but I believe it does what you want:
>>> ucte = sa.select(users).cte()
>>> q = sa.select(addresses).where(addresses.c.user_id == sa.any_(sa.func.array(sa.select(ucte.c.id).scalar_subquery())))
>>> with engine.connect() as conn:
...     for row in conn.execute(q):print(row)
... 
2024-07-04 08:26:56,448 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-07-04 08:26:56,448 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine WITH anon_1 AS 
(SELECT users.id AS id, users.name AS name, users.registration_date AS registration_date, users.encrypted AS encrypted, users.is_deleted AS is_deleted 
FROM users)
 SELECT addresses.id, addresses.user_id, addresses.email 
FROM addresses 
WHERE addresses.user_id = ANY (array((SELECT anon_1.id 
FROM anon_1)))
2024-07-04 08:26:56,448 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [cached since 17.82s ago] {}
(1, 1, 'alice@example.com')
(2, 2, 'bob@example.com')
(3, 3, 'carol@example.com')
(4, 4, 'dave@example.com')
(5, 5, 'eve@example.com')
(61, 1, 'a@example.com')
(62, 2, 'b@example.com')
(63, 3, 'c@example.com')
(64, 4, 'd@example.com')
(65, 5, 'e@example.com')
2024-07-04 08:26:56,450 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
>>> 

